# application not uploading apple app store after noon

Tags: ios

I am trying to upload app to itunes connect but it's showing that your "application being uploaded" from last 7 hours.I am try to upload via application Loader also but i can't upload.my internet working correct.
after noon it's not working.it's working correct in morning.it this any problem with apple server in india (GMT+ 5:30)i am facing this problem from last 20 days.I can't understand why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem before few days after trying for 4-5 times for half an hour i just restarted my machine and connected to my friends 3g network via hotspot and that uploaded app successfully to appstore.

You can check upload speed from Activity Monitor in utility(Data Sent/Sec).

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the app store uploader and firewall protected networks. The Ready For Upload Check will work successfully, but the upload will hang indefinitely.  The workaround is to do the upload from a different network - I tether my laptop to my phone for just the upload, or do it from my home broadband.